# Wrong location image in EPS file

Tags: graphics, eps, epstool

I produce an EPS figure with Gnuplot, with the command:

```
set term post solid rounded enhanced  color 'Helvetica, 16'
replot
```

I need to plot this figure on a poster which I am writing with LaTeX. I am writing the poster with the multicolumn environment, which doesn't recognise the command `\begin{figure}` (probably this is not essential to answer my question).

I am able to upload the figure, but I have the following problem: the image appears only in a corner of the figure, the remaining part of the figure is empty. I think it is a problem with the EPS file, as I find the same problem when I try to print directly the EPS file from the printer: when I open the file, the image correctly covers the whole "paper", but when I print it the image is located in a small corner of the A4 paper.

Can anyone help me? It's one day I am trying to solve this problem!!

Comment: It sounds like the EPS file has an incorrect bounding box (so it is including white space) you can supply an alternative bounding box `\includegraphics[bb= 100 200 300 400]` where the four numbers are the coordinates of the bottom left and top right in postscript points (`bp`) or you can use any other TeX unit.

Comment: A useful tip is to go `\fbox{\includegraphics.....}` then with the fbox you can see the space TeX is leaving for the figure and measure the distance to the bottom left corner of the actual figure

Comment: Perhaps only PostScript is output, perhaps `set terminal postscript eps` helps to get real Encapsulated PostScript. `epstool` helps to fix the bounding box, if it is not correct. However `epstool` does not convert a PostScript file to Encapsulated PostScript.

Comment: David and David: With bb and with \fbox I can then control the location of the image inside the figure? (The problem doens't involve the location of the figure in the poster, but of the image in the figure).

Comment: Heiko: I had the same problem adding "eps" after "terminal postscript" in Gnuplot

Comment: the fbox is just for debugging but yes by specifying a bb co0ordinates (and possibly also `clip`) in the includegraphics you can get latex to just include an arbitrary rectangle out of the full figure so if the rctangle you want is at the top left you just need to specify those coordinates. Note you should not have to do this:  the program generating the boundingbox comment in the EPS file is supposed to put the correct coordinates in, but that doesn't always happen. (gnuplot eps terminal normally gets it right though I thought)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the EPS file has an incorrect bounding box (so it is including white space) you can supply an alternative bounding box `\includegraphics[bb= 100 200 300 400]{..}` and top right in postscript points (bp) or you can use any other TeX unit.

A useful tip is to go `\fbox{\includegraphics.....}` then with the `\fbox` you can see the space TeX is leaving for the figure and measure the distance to the bottom left corner of the actual figure

The `\fbox` is just for debugging but by specifying BoundingBox coordinates (and possibly also `clip`) in the `\includegraphics` you can get latex to just include an arbitrary rectangle out of the full figure. So if the rectangle you want is at the top left you just need to specify those coordinates.

Note you should not have to do this: the program generating the boundingbox comment in the EPS file is supposed to put the correct coordinates in, but that doesn't always happen. (gnuplot eps terminal normally gets it right though I thought)